# HTMLUnit Page Load Time Calculation

Tags: java, htmlunit

I connect and load a page with [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) simply with the following code.

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net");
```

When `getPage` method completed, HTMLUnit is also finished parsing page (html, javascript etc).

How can I calculate just page download time? I need an indication or event that page download is completed and HTMLUnit is started parsing downloaded page content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution, after fully loading and parsing [HtmlPage](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html), it has a method to get [WebResponse](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/WebResponse.html). `WebResponse` gives load time with method getLoadTime()

> Returns the time it took to load this web response, in milliseconds.

```
page.getWebResponse().getLoadTime();
```